# Passing id from the file to the part of the link

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I need to test purchase flow of specific products on the page. To do it fast I wanted to pass product ids in scenario outline. But there are more than 100 of them, and they are repeatedly changed. So I needed to pasted them one by one to the table. So I wanted to save all ids from the database in some file. And later pass these ids from the file to the link. I heard that is possible to do that, when id is at the end of the link, but in my case it's in the middle. Is there any way to do that?

Here is how it looks right now:
  Scenario Outline: Checking purchase flow of specific product
    Given specific products is loaded `http://weburl/"<product_id>"/rest_of_url_address`

```
Examples:
    | product_id |
    | 1          |
    | 2          |
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.
I would suggest to have a wrapper feature, which will execute the database query and write the information and then generate the second feature file for `Checking purchase flow of specific product` so that you can add the product_ids' from to the examples table. Here is the draft.

```
Feature: Generate the feature file for 'Checking purchase flow of specific product' scenario validation.
Scenario: Run the DB query and generate the feature file
    Given User open connection to DB
    When  User run <query> and store the product ids
    And   User generate the feature file for scenario validation in <path> location
    Then  Feature file should be created in <path>  location
Examples:
| query           | path                        |
| query goes here | feature file path goes here |
```

The step definitions should connect to the database, run the query, store the query output to the global variable, and then write a file with the feature steps you specified in the original post. Then only additional thing that you have to do as part write to file is iterating through all the products in the query out  and add then to the feature file.

By this way you don't have to worry about the change in the product_ids', every time you run your suite the feature file will be generated with the product_ids dynamically.

Let me know if you need help in step def implementation details.

And the answer to your original question, yes you can use the product_id though it's not at the end. Your step was correct, but I would rather rather just pass the product_id to the step and handle navigating to the url in the step definition itself. Something like below.

```
When User loaded <product_id> product
```